# TypeError converting from pandas data frame to numpy array

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, encode

I am getting TypeError after converting pandas dataframe to numpy array (after using `pd.get_dummies` or by creating dummy variables from the dataframe using `df.apply` function) if the columns are of mixed types `int`, `str` and `float`.
I am not getting these errors if only using mixed types `int`, and `str`.

code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2]*2, 'b':['m','f']*2, 'c':[0.2, .1, .3, .5]})
dfd = pd.get_dummies(df, drop_first=True, dtype=int)
dfd.values
```

Error: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

I am getting error with `dfd.to_numpy()` too.
Even if I convert the dataframe `dfd` to `int` or `float` values using `df.astype`,
`dfd.to_numpy()` is still producing error. I am getting error even if only selecting columns which were not changed from `df`.

Goal:
I am encoding categorical features of the dataframe to one hot encoding, and then want to use `SelectKBest` with `score_func=mutual_info_classif` to select some features. The error produced by the code after fitting `SelectKBest` is same as the error produced by `dfd.to_numpy()` and hence I am assuming that the error is being produced when `SelectKBest` is trying to convert dataframe to numpy.
Besides, just using `mutual_info_classif` to get scores for corresponding features is working.

How should I debug it? Thanks.

[pandas converting to numpy error for mixed types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRXXb.jpg)

Comment: That code snippet works fine for me (pandas 1.3.2). What code throws that error? Could you post the full stack trace, not just the final error message?

Comment: I have added a picture which shows the full stack trace. my version of pandas is 1.1.3, and of python is 3.8. I started using python 3.8 (instead of 3.9) to match Tensorflow compatibility earlier. I ran the code in Kaggle notebook and it throws an error.
The code is working in google colab though.

Comment: I updated my python version and the error is gone.